# How do I scroll a WPF WebBrowser control to the end?

Tags: wpf

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="messageBufferWebBrowser" 
     controls:WebBrowserUtility.Body="{Binding MessageBuilder}"/>
```

I'm using this class to enable binding to the Body of the WebBrowser control

```
public static class WebBrowserUtility
{


    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Body", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserUtility), new PropertyMetadata(OnBodyChanged));

    public static string GetBody(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(BodyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBody(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string body)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(BodyProperty, body);
    }

    private static void OnBodyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var webBrowser = d as WebBrowser;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewValue as string) && webBrowser != null)
        {
            if (Application.Current.MainWindow != null && !DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(Application.Current.MainWindow))
            {
                webBrowser.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

That's my WebBrowser, I'm binding it to a StringBuilder property on the ViewModel.  How can I get the WebBrowser control to scroll to the end?

Answer (score 6):

If you cast the WebBrowser's Document property to a mshtml.HTMLDocument, then you can scroll to a specific position in the page (or the bottom by using the largest value possible):

```
var html = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
html.parentWindow.scroll(0, 10000000);
```

Note you have to add a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` in your project.

Comment: int.MaxValue don't work for me, but magic constant 10000000 do work

Comment: "Note this method only works if you handle the scroll inside of the WebBrowser.LoadCompleted event." - @DavyMac23